# Recharacterizing a Roth IRA contribution made in 2010?

Tags: united-states, ira, roth-ira, recharacterization

In 2010 I rollovered money from a 401(k) to a Roth IRA. At  the time, I chose to defer the taxable income to 2011 and 2012. However, I am now just learning about recharacterization. Is it too late for me to recharacterize my rollover, and is it even possible for me to do that? Also, would recharacterization decrease my taxable amount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deadline for recharacterizing the 2010 roll over was [October 17th 2011](http://www.irs.gov/retirement/article/0,,id=111413,00.html#5r).

> **What was the deadline to recharacterize a 2010 rollover or conversion to a Roth IRA?**
>
> You had until October 17, 2011 (because October 15, 2011, was a Saturday), to recharacterize your 2010 rollover or conversion to a Roth IRA if you filed your 2010 tax return on time, including extensions, and regardless of whether you requested an extension to file your 2010 tax return. For example, even if you did not request an extension to file your 2010 tax return and actually filed your return on or before April 18, 2011 (because April 15 was a holiday in the District of Columbia), you had until October 17, 2011, to recharacterize your 2010 Roth IRA rollover or conversion.